# PlaneGeometry and Directional Light

Tags: three.js

I've a problem with lightning and the plane geometry.
While creating the plane geometry with certain heightdata,
it doesn't seem to me, that the directional light affect the
mesh. There is still the same color overall :(

```
var geometry: THREE.PlaneGeometry
   = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 199, 199);

for (var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i++)
    geometry.vertices[i].z = this._heightmap.data[i];

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, 
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x1AAD2B }));

mesh.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(- Math.PI / 2));

this.screen.get("Scene").add(mesh);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);

light.position.set(0.8, 0.5, 1);
light.position.normalize();
this.screen.get("Scene").add(light);
```

http://s14.directupload.net/images/130703/jsfx9tr3.png

Must i create my own shader or is it a queston of options i need to perform?

Kind Regards
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't change the vertex normals; they are all ( 0, 1, 0 ).

Also, when you modify the vertices of a quad, the four vertices are most likely no longer planar. This will cause you all sorts of problems. ( google non-planar quads. )

You can avoid these problems by triangulating the `PlaneGeometry` first:

```
THREE.GeometryUtils.triangulateQuads( geometry );
```

Be advised that this function recomputes vertex normals. Have a look at the source so you understand what it is doing.

EDIT: three.js no longer supports quads; `PlaneGeometry` is now triangulated.

three.js r.66