# Loading a texture for a custom geometry causes "GL_INVALID_OPERATION" error

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm new to three.js and Web GL. In the following code I'm attempting to build a geometry and overlay an image on the geometry. When I do this, I recieve the following error.

```
[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
```

And the code:

```
var scene, camera, renderer, geometry, material, shape, particles, particlesMaterial, depthMap, depthMapDimensions, 
        particleSystem, particleCount, imageDimensions, vertextSpacing;

        imageDimensions = {
            width : 1080,
            height : 1080
        };

        depthMapDimensions = {
            width : 20,
            height : 20
        };

        vertextSpacing = {
            x : imageDimensions.width / depthMapDimensions.width,
            y : imageDimensions.height / depthMapDimensions.height
        }

        depthMap = [2.127567, 2.626095, 3.093391, 5.806643, 7.000000, 6.998367, 4.582537, 1.649688, 2.281374, 1.367736, 3.042042, 8.414231, 8.999998, 8.999999, 8.999998, 8.999999, 8.873376, 7.543515, 7.000446, 6.999999, 2.616741, 2.901183, 2.704453, 5.539745, 6.998835, 6.999611, 6.730113, 5.143857, 3.738796, 2.599236, 3.070265, 8.415504, 9.000000, 9.000000, 9.000000, 8.987292, 8.144215, 7.080783, 7.000000, 6.999999, 2.663667, 2.417611, 2.113292, 4.201475, 6.785589, 6.592422, 5.734896, 4.422761, 3.342103, 2.709703, 2.897975, 8.191135, 9.000000, 9.000000, 9.000000, 8.976017, 7.754744, 7.000002, 6.999999, 6.999999, 2.023745, 2.015293, 2.007580, 3.036786, 4.601620, 3.687377, 3.171844, 3.029730, 3.013251, 2.440641, 2.630903, 8.123555, 9.000000, 9.000000, 9.000000, 8.977840, 7.747422, 7.000000, 7.000000, 6.999999, 1.628098, 1.203436, 1.186097, 1.708180, 2.342594, 2.146624, 2.423483, 2.622567, 2.313046, 1.987591, 2.469096, 8.158025, 9.000000, 9.000000, 9.000000, 8.981831, 7.786616, 7.000000, 6.999999, 6.999999, -0.555659, -0.880668, -0.871480, -0.838492, -0.810392, -1.485775, -0.342942, 0.946382, 0.690366, 1.233515, 1.941243, 7.756371, 9.000000, 9.000000, 9.000000, 8.990389, 7.852441, 7.000000, 7.000000, 6.999999, -1.000000, -1.000000, -0.984316, -0.691079, -0.629077, -2.186010, -0.970196, 0.342872, 0.424878, 0.932589, 2.874258, 8.296001, 9.000000, 9.000000, 9.000000, 8.995690, 7.908023, 7.000005, 6.999999, 6.999999, -0.851585, -1.121474, -1.036169, 0.164867, 0.423980, -0.812104, -0.406743, 0.398304, 0.919763, 1.004518, 4.300021, 8.948308, 9.000000, 9.000000, 9.000000, 8.999194, 7.979087, 7.000435, 7.000000, 6.999999, -0.244019, -1.266773, -1.911372, -1.899194, -1.918406, -1.882335, -0.138694, 0.924173, 1.047134, 1.704133, 5.677461, 8.978599, 9.000000, 9.000000, 9.000000, 8.997765, 7.952168, 7.000490, 6.999999, 6.999999, -0.002295, -0.229373, -0.890307, -1.492303, -1.971603, -2.409527, -0.669644, 0.903183, 1.618998, 3.833140, 8.231560, 8.999952, 9.000000, 9.000000, 9.000000, 8.998553, 7.963422, 7.000403, 7.000000, 6.999999, 0.259623, 0.308825, 0.188026, -0.288844, -0.765398, -1.169663, -0.185390, 1.163299, 2.354378, 4.205532, 7.644516, 8.601805, 8.977304, 9.000000, 9.000000, 8.938294, 7.788084, 7.000249, 6.999999, 6.999999, 0.958028, 0.975304, 0.817023, 0.426733, 0.410694, 0.412157, 1.020823, 2.024281, 2.798701, 4.603123, 6.847786, 7.108493, 7.883547, 7.851915, 8.190980, 7.904086, 7.127523, 7.000080, 7.000000, 6.999999, 1.126147, 1.019150, 0.943917, 0.347039, 0.309151, 0.348898, 1.676575, 2.808274, 4.393281, 6.567654, 6.782535, 5.570826, 5.230399, 5.367241, 6.704737, 7.009059, 7.000690, 7.000002, 6.999999, 6.999999, 3.700892, 1.894742, 1.858719, 1.560115, 0.479706, 0.918191, 4.307354, 5.558891, 6.654403, 6.819664, 5.722251, 5.044959, 5.000000, 5.136653, 6.524189, 7.000000, 7.000000, 7.000000, 7.000000, 6.999999, 4.999616, 4.528327, 5.008296, 4.469171, 0.833706, 1.666193, 5.676921, 6.513674, 6.752453, 6.034523, 5.133774, 5.045851, 5.095105, 5.081395, 6.348025, 7.001901, 6.999999, 7.000000, 6.999999, 6.999999, 5.000000, 5.119382, 5.744474, 4.393946, 0.647267, 1.866858, 5.754084, 6.057019, 5.982171, 5.704051, 5.334934, 5.104724, 5.144377, 5.267979, 6.279684, 7.000135, 7.000000, 6.998665, 6.994687, 6.996591, 4.995393, 4.989268, 4.217751, 2.684558, 0.678229, 2.151997, 5.188607, 5.143293, 5.249653, 5.211581, 5.000000, 5.017254, 5.035619, 5.118769, 6.484150, 6.999919, 6.999999, 6.997725, 6.896475, 6.618106, 4.244583, 3.497095, 3.031803, 2.604051, 1.002629, 1.250600, 3.062681, 3.108018, 3.347652, 4.717236, 4.997857, 4.930811, 4.960470, 5.011927, 5.990526, 6.658366, 6.901021, 6.993680, 6.989233, 6.869072, 3.050878, 3.002264, 3.010682, 2.679759, 1.475260, 1.682000, 3.150505, 3.224762, 3.313409, 4.203482, 4.545135, 4.273145, 4.097577, 4.095634, 4.393558, 4.623382, 5.105378, 5.485256, 5.467518, 5.375812, 2.999999, 3.000000, 3.003595, 2.763143, 1.400769, 1.764386, 3.081679, 3.169889, 3.156426, 3.148278, 3.173652, 3.269066, 3.103685, 3.032829, 3.057311, 3.104075, 3.336546, 3.577827, 3.570257, 3.524523];

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .1, 1000);
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        geometry = new THREE.Geometry();


        console.log(geometry.vertices);


        //geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xFF0000, 
            map : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('IMG_0011-stk_00.jpg'),   
            wireframe : true
        });
        particleMaterials = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xFFFFFF,
            size: 10,
            transparent: true
        });

        //draw verticies
        for(var i = 0; i < depthMap.length; i++){
            var x, y, z, row, column;

            row = Math.ceil((i + 1) / depthMapDimensions.width);
            column = (i + 1) - (depthMapDimensions.width * (row - 1));

            //The x value of each vertex is a function of the width of the image 
            x = column;// vertextSpacing.x;
            //The y value of each vertex is a function of its calculated row;
            y = row * -1;// * vertextSpacing.y;
            //The depth of each vertex is the value from the depth map
            z = depthMap[i] * -1;  

            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));  

            //console.log(x,y,z);
        }

        //drawFaces
        var lastVertex = 0, j = 0;
        while(lastVertex  < (depthMap.length - 1)){

            if((j+1) % depthMapDimensions.width !== 0){
                //console.log(j, j + 1, j + depthMapDimensions.width, j + depthMapDimensions.width + 1 );
                geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face4( j, j + depthMapDimensions.width, j + depthMapDimensions.width + 1, j + 1 ) );
                lastVertex = j + depthMapDimensions.width + 1;
            }
            j++;
        }

        shape = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        shape.doubleSided = true;
        shape.overdraw = true;

        scene.add(shape);

        camera.position.z = 30;
        renderer.setClearColorHex(0x00000, 1);
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        (function render () {
            //shape.rotation.x += .01;
            //shape.rotation.y += .01;

            //renderer.render(scene, camera);

            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        })();
```

I understand this may have something to do with setting the "buffersNeedUpdate" and "uvsNeedUpdate" to true, but i'm not sure where this needs to be done. Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to specify `faceVertexUvs` in your custom geometry if you want to add a `map` for your material. See how `PlaneGeometry` adds them.
2. `mesh.doubleSided` has been replaced with `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`. Be sure to learn from the official three.js examples, and avoid old examples from the net.
3. Non-planar quads are dangerous. See: [PlaneGeometry and Directional Light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456164/planegeometry-and-directional-light/17456471#17456471) for more info.

three.js r.59

Comment: This is great but I'm still a bit confused. If I want the image to wrap the entire geometry, how should I define my facevertexuvs?

Comment: See my suggestion in 1.